# static site pagination with google app engine

Tags: regex, google-app-engine, yaml, jekyll, octopress

I have an octopress/jekyll blog that I am trying to host with Google App Engine. Here's a different SO question that got me started: [How to Regex for static webpage on Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194876/how-to-regex-for-static-webpage-on-google-app-engine)

However, I would ALSO like to get pretty urls working (with no index.html required at the end of the url).

e.g. /blog/post/ instead of /blog/post/index.html

For some of this I can wire up explicit rules (though it's pretty ugly). For the pagination pages (/blog/page2 for example) there is no way to know how many there will be and therefore can't wire them up.

I dimly suspect this will require a python script, but I'm wondering if there might be some regex magic that would accomplish the same thing? Either way, anyone have an idea? An example of a script that might work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with octopress/jekyll, but as far as GAE is concerned, I think you may want to review this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047515/google-app-engine-php-routing-query-params/25049199#25049199 which may help.. 

In short, you can just map your handlers to the urls you prefer.. And as far as the page2/3/4 then you could technically just make that one page (display?page=1,2,3,4)

Comment: Octopress outputs naked HTML. If I'm understanding your suggestion, I can't really provide arguments on the URL. The page MUST be at /page2 because that's where it is.